# Move folders and files to a folder

Tags: php

I need a lot of help!
I would make the code below, I copied the folder along with the files inside it to the folder "Backup_Archives" ie in the folder uploads will have:

```
uploads/a1/arq.pdf
uploads/a2/arq2.pdf
```

So the Backup folder will be after copying:

```
Backup_Archives/a1 /arq.pdf
Backup_Archives/a2/arq2.pdf
```

I would like the folders / files to be copied and after the copy is done, delete all the files inside the subfolders, such as:

```
uploads/a1/ "arq.pdf"
uploads/a2/ "arq2.pdf"
```

CODE:

```
<?php
    // pega a lista de arquivos com a extensão pdf.
    $list = glob(__dir__.'/uploads/a1/*.pdf');

    // diretorio aonde serão remanejados. 
    $save = __dir__.'/uploads/Backup_Arquivos/';
        echo 'Nenhum arquivo será movido caso nenhuma mensagem abaixo apareça!<br>';
    foreach ($list as $value) {
        if (rename($value, $save.basename($value))) {
            echo '<br>Item da Enviado com êxito! <br>';
        }
    }
?>
```

Note: My code is only moving the files from a folder to the Backup_Files folder.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? If so, please include them.

Answer (score 1):

You are moving files not copying

> bool rename ( string old_name, string new_name [, resource context])
>
> bool copy ( string source, string dest)
>
> bool unlink ( string filename, resource context)

So in your case, you don't have to delete the files.

If you want to copy and then delete the file

should look like this

```
<?php
// pega a lista de arquivos com a extensão pdf.
$list = glob(__dir__.'/uploads/a1/*.pdf');

// diretorio aonde serão remanejados.
$save = __dir__.'/uploads/Backup_Arquivos/';
echo 'Nenhum arquivo será movido caso nenhuma mensagem abaixo apareça!<br>';
foreach ($list as $value) {
    if (copy($value, $save.basename($value))) {
        echo '<br>Item da Enviado com êxito! <br>';
        unlink($value);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: How do I get the folder to go together and not just the files?

Comment: do you mean "Subfolders"? I'm not sure about the question